# Firebase Cloud Messaging not working in Mozilla firefox incognito mode

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase cloud messaging working normally in mozilla , but when i tried same in incognito mode this error lead to crashing app.

This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser) mozilla

Anyway through which we can handle this.

Answer (score 4):

"In Firefox, Service Worker APIs are hidden and cannot be used when the user is in private browsing mode."

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

You can't use Messaging in Firefox's private mode, because it depends on Service Worker APIs. There is no way to circumvent this.

You can check if messaging is supported by calling `messaging.isSupported()`. Example code:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/messaging';

if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
  // messaging is supported
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
} else {
  // messaging is not supported
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mertcan-mermerkaya. So , is there any way through which i can check firefox private mode and disable fcm .

Comment: No problem. Added to my answer.

Comment: it says isSupported is not a function

Comment: The correct call is `firebase.messaging.isSupported()`, DO NOT USE `firebase.messaging().isSupported`... because it is not a function!

Comment: Also check your cookie settings, see bug report at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1429714